# Rails / Heroku - How can I anti-virus scan an uploaded file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, heroku

How is it possible to scan a uploaded file for viruses, trojans etc.?

Just thinking about preventing some users to upload some nasty stuff.

I am using Heroku and Amazon S3.

Comment: There are a few suggestions in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104985/antivirus-scanning-service), and that person was also using Heroku.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check out this](http://scanii.com)

It supports a REST/JSON antivirus web service.

Comment: Is it worth it? I would just think hackers would test the file with scanii online scanner and if it passes then upload it to the website. ¨¨

Answer (score 1):

For the passers-by asking the same question:

[Metascan](https://www.metascan-online.com/en). It's free and has a simple API!

Comment: how to integerate this in `Rails` application ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone approaching this in future we recently created [CarrierWave::AttachmentScanner](https://github.com/attachmentscanner/carrierwave-attachmentscanner) to easily integrate virus and malware scanning into Rails and CarrierWave.

The plugin basically hooks into file uploads using carrierwave and sends the request to a JSON/REST web service to check the files.

If the file matches a known signature then it will raise a `CarrierWave:: IntegrityError`.

Answer (score 1):

### Open Source: [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) and [Clamby](https://github.com/kobaltz/clamby)

1. Install ClamAV:

   **macOS**

   ```
   brew install clamav
   ```

   **Ubuntu**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install clamav clamav-daemon -y
   ```
2. Setup `after_create` callback in your Rails app to scan new Files:

   ```
   after_create :scan_for_viruses

   def scan_for_viruses
     raise "Virus discovered!" if Clamby.virus?( self.path )
   end
   ```

Comment: ClamAV looks like a nice solution. But isn't it a problem that the file has to be uploaded completly before being able to scan it? Like this the potential virus is already on theh arddrive of the server. Right?

Comment: @fuuman Not sure how else you would be able to do it, besides using a third party service. But just because the file needs to be uploaded to scan it, doesn't mean it's being accessed or called immediately. At our company they are kept in quarantine until they are cleared by various checks, including ClamAV. If you were really cautious, you could upload them to a separate, limited-access server first before adding them to your primary server stack once they are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clamav buildpack to add virus-scan capabilities to your heroku-app.
Then in your Rails app use the ratonvirus gem to connect the clamav virus scanner with your rails app.
In rails you just have to add

```
validates :file, antivirus: true
```

to your model that you want to scan.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to my blog post about running a ClamAV (using Clamby gem) antivirus as a service on Kubernetes and a DRY implementation to use it inside your RoR app:

https://www.shebanglabs.io/rails-antivirus-clamby-clamav/

Also, you can just pick the part that you like and combine it with your stack of choice.